# The homology of $\Omega T^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

As part of a bigger plan for conquering Europe, I have to compute the integral homology of the loop space of the $n$-torus $T^n = S^1\times \cdots \times S^1$.

The plan is: compute $H_*(\Omega T^n,\mathbb{Z})$ via Serre spectral sequence (spectral sequences are part of the standard training of any supervillain) using $\Omega T^n\to pt\to T^n$ and then double-check the result using Künneth theorem.

The problem is that $\Omega T^n$ is a wicked space.

Serre spectral sequence works well when the base of a fibration is simply connected, and this is not the case. It is obviously possible to adapt the argument to a $\pi_1(B)\neq 0$ case, but (in the most powerful theorem I know) the fiber $F$ has to be connected, which is not the case ($\Omega T^n$ seems to have many${}^{\mathbb Z}$ connected components).

I tried everything I know, so please help me:

1. Shall I forsake my evil plan?
2. Is it possible to compute $H_*(\Omega T^n,\mathbb{Z})$ using Serre SS?
3. Shall I trust a lazy Kunneth computation which tells me that all $\Omega T^n$ have a countable number of contractible connected components?

Comment: You can always resort to SSS with local coefficients, which converges reasonably well even with a non-trivial action of $\pi_1(B)$ on the homology of $F$

Comment: As I said above, the sharpest result I know is Thm 5.1 in McCleary's book (2nd ed.), where it is explicitly stated that $F$ has to be connected. Can this assumption be removed, at what cost?

Comment: I was forgetting about the requirement that the fiber have a nice action of the fundamental group of the base. Is there a particular reason that you care about this example?

Comment: No particular reason. I wanted it to be part of a series of exercises in "computations in algebraic topology". Also, I liked the idea to familiarize with high-tech by using it to prove low-tech results (Kunneth already gives an answer that you can use as double-check); I didn't expect such a mess! Now I think it's an instructive example since it's involved enough to force you to stretch the standard argument.

Comment: But... you already know the answer is a product of $\mathbb{Z}$'s. You know exactly how many. I think computing the homology/cohomology of classical groups might be more fun.

Comment: I remember that my first acquaintance with spec seqs was "pretend that you don't know the  5 lemma and the LES in co/homology and prove them using a SS", so I like this kind of boring exercises. Maybe it's a matter of taste.

Comment: What made me suspect that one can't use the standard argument in this case is that it seems that $E^\infty_{1,0}\cong H_0(\Omega T^n,\mathbb{Z})^n$; this is impossible?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Serre spectral sequence is an imperfect tool for calculating the homology of the fiber when the base space is not simply connected. Then you have to use (co)homology with local coefficient systems and you can't get the inductive methods started, because these types of (co)homology do not give you enough information.

In your case, it's instructive to look at $n=1$, so your base is $S^1$. Then the homology groups of the fiber have an action of $\Bbb Z$, so we can just think of that as the generator $t$ of $\Bbb Z$ acting. *All* that we learn from the Serre spectral sequence is that:

- the operator $t-1$ is an isomorphism on all positive degree homology groups of the fiber, and
- on the degree zero homology group, the operator $t-1$ is injective with cokernel $\Bbb Z$.

That's simply not enough information to recover the homology of the fiber.

Answer (score 8):

Long exact sequence of fibration $pt\to T^n$ gives us that $\pi_k(\Omega T^n)=\pi_{k+1}(T^n)$, so $\pi_k(\Omega T^n)=0$ when $k>0$. Since $\pi_1(T^n)=\mathbb Z^n$ transitive acts by permutations on the connected components of $\Omega T^n$, all the components are homeomorphic. And as $T^n$ is a $CW$-complex, the space $\Omega T^n$ has the homotopy type of $CW$-complex, so each its component is contractable.